# kubectl cannot authenticate with AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I cannot get `kubectl` to authenticate with the EKS Kubernetes instance my coworker created. I've followed [the](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/configure-kubectl.html): the AWS CLI can run `aws eks` commands (I'm an AWS Full Administrator), and the heptio authenticatior is in my path and can generate tokens.

When I run `kubectl` I get this error:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.4", 
GitCommit:"5ca598b4ba5abb89bb773071ce452e33fb66339d", GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2018-06-06T15:22:13Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.6", Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client
to provide credentials)
```

Here's my ~/.kube/config file. It's the exact kubeconfig my coworker can successfully use.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://myinstance.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
    certificate-authority-data: base64_cert                                                                                                                                                                                                   name: kubernetes                                                                                                                                                                                                                          contexts:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   - context:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      cluster: kubernetes                                                                                                                                                                                                                         user: aws                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 name: aws
current-context: aws
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: aws
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: heptio-authenticator-aws
      args:
        - "token"
        - "-i"
        - "dev-qa"
        # - "-r"
        # - "<role-arn>"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I needed to add my IAM user to the `mapUsers` section of the ConfigMap `configmap/aws-auth`, per [these AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html).

You can edit the configmap using the same AWS user that initially created the cluster.

```
$ kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth

apiVersion: v1
data:
mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::555555555555:role/devel-worker-nodes-NodeInstanceRole-74RF4UBDUKL6
    username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::555555555555:user/admin
    username: admin
    groups:
        - system:masters
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/ops-user
    username: ops-user
    groups:
        - system:masters
mapAccounts: |
    - "111122223333"
```

Comment: This answer worked in my case. If the cluster was created by an IAM user then that user gets automatically mapped into the cluster. HOWEVER ... any other IAM users have to be manually mapped/added.

Comment: I get an error: `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "configmap"`
My understanding is that you have to log in to edit the configmap, resulting in a catch-22 scenario

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but just wanted to clarify that as of 2019 EKS now creates the config file for you: aws eks --region region update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name and you can download the config map from: curl -O https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2019-02-11/aws-auth-cm.yaml  it is all here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html

Comment: `kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth` doesn't work. it wants `please enter username` which is a cyclic error as this page deals with not being able to authenticate.Therefore this solution is irrelavent.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, AWS doesn't yet have a command like GKE's "gcloud container clusters get-credentials", which creates kubectl config for you. So, you need to create kubectl config file manually.

As mentioned in [creating a kubeconfig for Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html) document, you should get two things from the cluster:

1. Retrieve the endpoint for your cluster. Use this for the `<endpoint-url>` in your kubeconfig file.

   ```
   aws eks describe-cluster --cluster-name <cluster-name>  --query cluster.endpoint
   ```
2. Retrieve the certificateAuthority.data for your cluster. Use this for the `<base64-encoded-ca-cert>` in your kubeconfig file.

   ```
   aws eks describe-cluster --cluster-name <cluster-name>  --query cluster.certificateAuthority.data
   ```

Create the default kubectl folder if it does not already exist.

```
mkdir -p ~/.kube
```

Open your favorite text editor and paste the following kubeconfig code block into it.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: <endpoint-url>
    certificate-authority-data: <base64-encoded-ca-cert>
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: aws
  name: aws
current-context: aws
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: aws
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: heptio-authenticator-aws
      args:
        - "token"
        - "-i"
        - "<cluster-name>"
        # - "-r"
        # - "<role-arn>"
      # env:
        # - name: AWS_PROFILE
        #   value: "<aws-profile>"
```

Replace the `<endpoint-url>` with the endpoint URL that was created for your cluster.
Replace the `<base64-encoded-ca-cert>` with the certificateAuthority.data that was created for your cluster.
Replace the `<cluster-name>` with your cluster name.

Save the file to the default kubectl folder, with your cluster name in the file name. For example, if your cluster name is devel, save the file to `~/.kube/config-devel`.

Add that file path to your `KUBECONFIG` environment variable so that `kubectl` knows where to look for your cluster configuration.

```
export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config-devel
```

(Optional) Add the configuration to your shell initialization file so that it is configured when you open a shell.

For Bash shells on macOS:

```
echo 'export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config-devel' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

For Bash shells on Linux:

```
echo 'export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config-devel' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Test your configuration.

```
kubectl get svc
```

Output:

```
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
svc/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.100.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   1m
```

*Note*
If you receive the error `"heptio-authenticator-aws": executable file not found in $PATH`, then your `kubectl` is not configured for Amazon EKS. For more information, see [Configure kubectl for Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/configure-kubectl.html).

Comment: I have followed that same documentation and created my kube config file with the server and certificate data filled in, but I'm getting the error listed in my question.

Comment: There are several closed issues on that error. Most of them was caused by errors in configuration file. Try to check your configuration file for tabs instead of spaces. It may cause the file to read incorrectly by kubectl.

Answer (score 1):

Things have gotten a bit simpler over time. To get started on Linux (or indeed WSL) you will need to:

1. [Install the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html) and configure valid AWS CLI credentials (`aws configure` or e.g. use AWS SSO to generate time-limited credentials on the fly)
2. [Install eksctl and kubectl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html)
3. [Install aws-iam-authenticator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html)

At this point, assuming you already have a running Kubernetes Cluster in your AWS account you can generate/update the kube configuration in $HOME/.kube/config with this one command:

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --name test`

Where `test` is your cluster name according to the AWS Console (or `aws eks list-clusters`).

You can now run for instance `kubectl get svc` without getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in your AWS configuration variables in line with your command (or set them as global variables).

Example:

```
AWS_PROFILE=profile_name kubectl get all
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by fixing the base64 encoded certificate in the kubeconfig file I created. The documentation is a little confusing because it says to use the --cluster-name switch with the aws cli for the EKS service and for me the --name switch worked. This printed the base64 value to the cli and I copy pasta it into the kubeconfig file saved and it worked.

```
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=[YOUR_ID_HERE] AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=[YOUR_SECRET_HERE] aws eks describe-cluster --name staging --query cluster.certificateAuthority.data
```